# Quick sort not working after the first partition

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to write my first quick sort algorithm for hours, but still not getting it right. The goal is to write a quick sort code for sorting an array. I want to use two functions: recursive function quick_sort, and partition function.

I found the partition function seems work correctly on each sub-array generated by the divide and conquer, but the returned total array seemed not changed after the first partition (the first partition has an effect, while the second, third partitions,..., seemed have no effect).

I must have missed something here, any hints?

```
def partition(a, first, last):      
    x = a[0]
    j = 0

    for i in range((first+1), (last+1)):

        if x >= a[i]:
            j = j + 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]    
    a[0], a[j] = a[j], a[0]

    return j 

def quicksort(a):
    quick_sort(a, 0, len(a) - 1)

def quick_sort(a, first, last):

    if first < last:     
        j = partition(a, first, last)
        # devide a into two parts and do quicksort respectively
        quicksort(a[:j])
        quicksort(a[j+1:])

    return a

a = [6.5, 4, 2, 3, 9, 8, 9, 4, 7, 6, 1]
quicksort(a)
```

Comment: a[:j] is different array, a copy. You should use quicksort(a, first, j), quicksort(a, j+1, last)

Comment: That is exactly where I missed! Thanks a lot UmNyobe

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
quicksort(a[:j])
quicksort(a[j+1:])
```

For

```
quick_sort(a,first,j-1)
quick_sort(a,j+1,last)
```

Since you are calling `quicksort(a)` this willl do again only the first iteration, bc you set the low and high as the first iteration all the time, so to preserve it you should call the recursive one using j